# Jquery move element

Tags: jquery, onclick, append

guys so basically I am trying to move a div into another div with jquery but I only want it to move when clicked. how would I go about this would it be an if else statement?

Comment: Please see **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Sample

```
<div id="container">
  Main Div ......
</div>
<div id="childDiv">
 Child div ..........
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#childDiv" ).click(function() {
    $( "#container" ).append($( "#childDiv" ));
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$( "#childDiv" ).click(function() {
  $( "#container" ).append($( "#childDiv" ));
});
```

```css
div{ margin: .5em; } 
    #container{ border: solid 1px red; }
    #childDiv {border: solid 1px gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Main Div ......
</div>
<div id="childDiv">
  Child div ..........
</div>
```